# nokogiri and xpath -- nested looping with data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to loop through the  elements in each  but am having issues with the inner loop below. It appears to me the xpath pattern '*/td' is not returning any results. I'm expecting to see the data inside the  tags printed to stdout. I'm using nokogiri.

I'm pasting this into my rails console:

```
require 'nokogiri'
f = File.open("public/index.html")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
f.close

doc.xpath('//*[@id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel4"]/tbody/tr').each do |row|
  puts "row= " + row.to_s
  row.xpath('*/td').each do |td|
    puts "td= " + td
  end
end
```

And here's the output from the console:

```
row= <tr id="208894">
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1"><a href="/alarmpoint/UserDevices.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=KpBkJeR08z6mdgIY4sPrzAixAYz%2BqH6ZPkanPQ24VqQFpjRFPQiWigQHttJBTMFaCLEBjP6ofpk%2B%0D%0ARqc9DbhWpI1nHAqm8ex%2BxOmu7xYUNxRSU0XUo1xoRw%3D%3D" name="user1" id="user1" class="details">User 1</a></td>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">PERSON</td>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">0</td>
</tr>
row= <tr id="207792">
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1"><a href="/alarmpoint/UserDevices.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=KpBkJeR08z6AOzsYzBi7dAixAYz%2BqH6ZPkanPQ24VqQFpjRFPQiWigQHttJBTMFaCLEBjP6ofpk%2B%0D%0ARqc9DbhWpI1nHAqm8ex%2BxOmu7xYUNxRSU0XUo1xoRw%3D%3D" name="user2" id="user2" class="details">User 2</a></td>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">PERSON</td>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">5</td>
</tr>
=> 0
```

Here's the html I'm parsing:

```
<table class="duty-report-level1" id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1">
<caption></caption>
<thead>

<tr>
<th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1" class="duty-report-lt-header">c</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1">
<table class="duty-report-level2" id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel2">
<caption></caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1">Group Name</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">Group Time Zone</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">Default Devices</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:4">Supervisors</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1"><a href="/alarmpoint/GroupDetails.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=TJZuNquzHUgWcre8AVcKpAFRUsezgPKzbHn7hwtTf9Ei0C2PJ8QYcKIy8OkorCWT8HDTAzkon1ls%0D%0AefuHC1N%2F0SLQLY8nxBhwesdd7Zeg6NzvCfuzRqLg5g%3D%3D" name="team1" id="team1" class="details">Team 1</a></td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2" class="centered-text">US/Pacific</td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3" class="centered-text"><img src="/static/images/icon_boolean_false.png" alt="No" border="0"></td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:4">
<values>
</values><a href="/alarmpoint/UserDevices.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=KpBkJeR08z7AnuRhH67H6AixAYz%2BqH6ZPkanPQ24VqQFpjRFPQiWigQHttJBTMFaCLEBjP6ofpk%2B%0D%0ARqc9DbhWpI1nHAqm8ex%2BxOmu7xYUNxRSU0XUo1xoRw%3D%3D" name="mgr1" id="mgr1" class="details">Mgr 1</a>
<br>








</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1" class="no-padding" colspan="4">
<table class="duty-report-level3" id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel3">
<caption></caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1" class="th-left">a</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2" class="">b</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1" class="no-padding" colspan="2">
<table class="duty-report-level4" id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel4">
<caption></caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1">Recipient</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">Category</th><th id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">Escalation</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr id="208894">

<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1"><a href="/alarmpoint/UserDevices.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=KpBkJeR08z6mdgIY4sPrzAixAYz%2BqH6ZPkanPQ24VqQFpjRFPQiWigQHttJBTMFaCLEBjP6ofpk%2B%0D%0ARqc9DbhWpI1nHAqm8ex%2BxOmu7xYUNxRSU0XUo1xoRw%3D%3D" name="user1" id="user1" class="details">User 1</a></td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">PERSON</td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">0</td>
</tr>
<tr id="207792">
<td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:1"><a href="/alarmpoint/UserDevices.do;jsessionid=17gaw4aw5pv8s?_data=KpBkJeR08z6AOzsYzBi7dAixAYz%2BqH6ZPkanPQ24VqQFpjRFPQiWigQHttJBTMFaCLEBjP6ofpk%2B%0D%0ARqc9DbhWpI1nHAqm8ex%2BxOmu7xYUNxRSU0XUo1xoRw%3D%3D" name="user2" id="user2" class="details">User 2</a></td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:2">PERSON</td><td headers="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel1:header:3">5</td>
</tr>




</tbody>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry about that, I'm expecting to see the data inside the <td> tags printed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a minor change to your XPath:

```
doc.xpath('//*[@id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel4"]/tbody/tr').each do |row|
  # puts "row= " + row.to_s
  row.xpath('./td').each do |td|
    puts "td= " + td.text
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
td= User 1
td= PERSON
td= 0
td= User 2
td= PERSON
td= 5
```

Using `./td` as the XPath for `td` basically means "from this point look down one".

Personally, unless you absolutely need XPath, I recommend using CSS accessors. They are more readable, and often much more simple:

```
doc.search('#WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel4 tbody tr').each do |row|
  row.search('td').each do |td|
    puts "td= " + td.text
  end
end
```

I recommend using `search` instead of `css` or `xpath` and `at` instead of `at_css` or `at_xpath`. There is no real magic going on when you choose one over the other and you only have to remember two different methods.

Comment: It takes a little while to get the hang of parsing XML/HTML but once you do it makes it SO easy to tear apart pages and XML data. XPath is very powerful but starts to look like line-noise to me, which is why I prefer CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression in the inner loop is evaluated relative to each `tr`, so you want to use `td` (which selects *children* `td` elements of the context `tr`) and not `*/td` (which selects *grandchildren* `td` elements).

Full code:

```
doc.xpath('//*[@id="WhoIsOnDutyTableLevel4"]/tbody/tr').each do |row|
    puts "row= " + row.to_s
    row.xpath('td').each do |td|
        puts "td= " + td
    end
end
```